# Is there any risk to having 2 devices simultaneously connected to the same display?

Tags: hardware

I have two devices. One of them is my personal desktop machine, and the other one is my work laptop which I do not own and have very little control over.

With the security of the sector I work in, I am wary of connecting any personal devices to the laptop, following all the typical safeguards and only using company issued accessories etc...

However, connecting these laptops to *personal* non-networked displays is a common occurrence.

In my setup (diagram below), my personal desktop is connected to my monitor via a DisplayPort cable coming from its Nvidia GPU, and the laptop is connected to the same monitor via a USB-C to HDMI cable (via Intel Integrated Graphics):

[image: Diagram showing 2 separate devices connected to the same shared monitor]

When working on the laptop, I have developed the unfounded habit of unplugging my desktop from the display. My thought process is that due to my desktop being laden with lots of software & games etc..., it carries that extra risk of having potential vulnerabilities due to its inherently larger attack surface. Because of this, I avoid having any hardware 'bridge' between the two when the work laptop is in use.

Is this a completely unsubstantiated fear, or are there any documented risks to devices sharing a display medium in this manner?

*I know modern HDMI specs like the one supported by my monitor actually allow bidirectional data transmission for things such as [ARC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#:%7E:text=Introduced%20in%20HDMI%201.4%2C%20HDMI,the%20source%20device%20(ARC).), however, I am unaware of how such things work in the DP world. If both cables were just one way with the devices pushing data to the monitor, I would be less concerned.*

Comment: It's total paranoia, but if your job sector gives you a reason to be totally paranoid, then using fully separate displays isn't a stupid precaution because it avoids breaking the air-gap.

Comment: DP connections are bidirectional, too. At minimum information about the connected monitor is send. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort#Auxiliary_channel

Comment: Like @user253751 said: Is there a hypothetical possibility? Yes. Is some adversary going to spend the time and money to 1. Compromise your personal computer 2. Find a way to potentially exploit and pivot through the monitor 3. Find a way to exploit your work laptop's display interface? Depends what is on your work laptop, but for most people, probably not.

Comment: @multithr3at3d A hypothetical possibility isn't an actual possibility. It's hypothetically possible this could be possible in some circumstances and it's also very likely that it's not possible in Reece's circumstances (or anyone else's)